# Foundation source ordering confusion

Tags: zurb-foundation

I have a row setup like so:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 small-push-12 large-6 columns">
        <!-- Content -->
    </div>
    <div class="small-12 small-pull-12 large-6 columns">
        <!-- Content -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Basically, I want the second column to be pulled before the first column when the screen is small, but keep it at proper order for large screens.

What am I doing wrong here? The document reflows like it always does.

Also, I do realize I can just reverse the order in the HTML itself and it'll work, but just curious if it's possible to make it work this way.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your question prompted me to look at Foundation’s SCSS source code to see how the grid was implemented since like you I was having trouble getting my columns to shift as I wanted.  In the time spent finding an answer I’ve now forgotten what I’d needed to find out originally but having gained insight as to how the grid works I know it will now be much easier to use and I’ll feel more confident that my work is correct.  I’ll try to provide some of that insight here.

The simple answer to your question is, No, you can’t make Foundation swap a block of columns in the way you’ve done it. [I’ll call them *columns* as opposed to *grid columns* that refer to Foundation’s (usually 12) base columns.]  Assuming it might have worked I’d say that the code you wrote would be correct.  The actual reason it fails to work is because *there are no 12 column push or pull classes defined in Foundation for small, medium, large or any media size range."  Thus, when the media screen size is "small" (in your case) the push and pull classes are silently ignored by CSS and you end up with two columns on two rows in the original order.

**The general rule is that you can’t push or pull columns from one row to another; you can only move them along the same row.**  After seeing that I reread your question which began, "I have a row setup like so…"  But that’s not true since the intention is to produce *two* rows.  That one can create multiple rows with one column(s) definition is, I think, just a side effect of how CSS floats work.

Here’s what happens (excuse me for anthropomorphizing the CSS attributes…it's just easier to talk about them as "doing something to something" and often seems to be the best way to clearly understand what's happening):

For every column you specify, it’s width is determined using the current grid column width (plus some "gutter" for spacing) multiplied by the specified number of grid columns from the class name used (large-6, small-2, etc.).  Since they have been given the *float* attribute they are then lined up one against the next starting at the beginning of the row. If there is not enough room on one row to display all the columns the line of columns is split and continues on the "line" below, and so on; those that don't fit are moved to the next row (and so on). Without other classes specified each column will be displayed in this initial position. This is how multiple rows can be formed from one column(s) definition.

When you add *push* and *pull* classes the CSS *right* and *left* attributes are added to those described above.  The offset determined by the specified *push* or *pull* class is used to calculate the relative shift which is used to reorder columns if necessary. But the *left* and *right* CSS attributes know nothing about where these column-blocks have come from or that there is any row but the one they work on. So each column is moved along the line where it was initially placed and if the amount of shift moves the column outside of the row boundary it will be placed (or partially placed) to the left or right of the row (and possibly out of sight). That’s the reason that your proposed process won't work in general though in your case, as mentioned above, you used a class that wasn't defined (small-push-12) and got a different effect. If you play around a bit with the lower numbered *push* and *pull* classes (1 through 11) you can see more clearly how the columns  are pushed part way off a row. (the way it is currently done by Foundation, at least) and why I now think (since at first I thought it might be possible myself) that being able to create multiple rows in the base case is a beneficial "side effect" of how CSS happens to work.

For anyone wanting to improve their CSS understanding or who uses Foundation, I highly recommend taking some time to work through one or more of the features that Zurb has implemented in the framework.  I find that the SCSS definitions are well designed and cleanly coded (though perhaps not to everyone’s liking since, IMHO, CSS coding opinions seem to be as inflammatory as Mac/Windows opinions and often evoke the same fervor when expressed).

Answer (score 8):

Found the solution in a separate thread! Start with the order you want in the source for mobile, then use the push/pull classes to bend it around for the LARGER sizes. In other words, approach it from the opposite end.

[Change order for Foundation small-12 column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22042690/change-order-for-foundation-small-12-column)

Comment: Note that foundation 6 uses ordering instead of push/pull: eg. you could use medium-order-2 and medium-order-1 classes to switch two columns at medium resolution up.
see https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/flexbox-utilities.html#source-ordering