# Change order for Foundation small-12 column

Tags: zurb-foundation

I have a layout with an image to the left and a text on the right for medium and large views. I want to the text to be BEFORE the image on "small-12" though.

The pull/push mechanism does not seem to work with "xxx-12" columns.

These are my divs:

```
<div class="large-4 medium-6 small-12">Image</div>
<div class="large-8 medium-6 small-12">Text</div>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here you go. You are missing columns. You want to order the small content first. Then push pull http://cdpn.io/xfJph

Comment: Just bumped into this with a similar task.  The answer I was looking for was "You want to order the small content first. Then push pull". Thanks

Comment: I was in similar situation too, (didn't want to use flex box), ended up doing this, as @MatthiasMax said to Rafi, thanks a lot.