# Source Ordering columns on small screens

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

[this is the site](http://www.netu.co.il/true/),
when i re-size to small screens, it looks like this:

[image]

I need the second yellow block replaced by the bottom block and i cant get it done with foundation's pull & push option

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have a read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21147499/foundation-source-ordering-confusion

Comment: from what I've understand there is only option to reorder the columns horizontally in the same row but not vertically even if they are in the same row.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you want the final product to look like this:

[image: I think this is what you are looking for.]

The current order of the row you want changed is DEAD MAIN’S CACHE (Text), BENJAMIN (Portrait), and then PROTECT YOUR NECK (Coffee Bean?).

Switch DEAD MAIN’S CACHE (Text) and PROTECT YOUR NECK (Coffee Bean?).

Remove all references to `small` and use push and pull to correct the order for large screens.

Your current code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 small-push-12 large-4 columns">DEAD MAIN’S CACHE (Text)</div>
    <div class="large-4 columns">BENJAMIN (Portrait)</div>
    <div class="small-12 small-push-12 large-4 columns">PROTECT YOUR NECK (Coffee Bean?)</div>
</div>
```

My suggestion:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-4 large-push-8 columns">PROTECT YOUR NECK (Coffee Bean?)</div>
    <div class="large-4 columns">BENJAMIN (Portrait)</div>
    <div class="large-4 large-pull-8 columns">DEAD MAIN’S CACHE (Text)</div>
</div>
```

In essence, design for mobile first and use the push/pull to "fix" larger screen sizes.

If I misunderstood your question please let me know.

I hope that helps.