# Simple example of Zurb Foundation source ordering classes (w/fiddle)

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I'm missing something about the usage of the source-ordering classes in Foundation 5 (`*-push-*` and `*-pull-*`) I created a JSfiddle to illustrate the gap between my understanding and the world as it is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/m45fQ/)

The case is pretty simple: I have a row with with two columns. On Large viewports, I want them side by side, each 6 columns in width. On Small viewports, I want them stacked, each 12 columns in width, with the second column now above the first.

```
[ A ][ B ] --resize--> [ B ]
                       [ A ]
```

what I get is

```
[ A ][ B ] --resize--> ____[ A ]
                       [ B ]____
```

here's the code again

```
<body>
    <div class="row ">
        <div class="large-6 small-12 small-push-6 columns large-reset-order">
            <p>A:  On large screens, I should be the first element in the row, taking up half the grid, i.e. 6 columns</p>
            <p>Then again, on small screens I should be the second element.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="large-6 small-12 small-pull-6 columns large-reset-order">
            <p>B:  On large screens, I should be the second element in the row, i.e. 6 columns</p>
            <p>Of course, on small screens, I should show up first!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21147499/foundation-source-ordering-confusion) but I don't think it answers mine. First, I'm not using push-12, so there is a class defined. Second, what I'm doing looks, in my confusion, a lot like the last example in the source ordering section of the [Foundation docs](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
<body>
    <div class="row ">
        <div class="large-6 small-12 large-push-6 columns ">
            <p>A:  On large screens, I should be the first element in the row, taking up half the grid, i.e. 6 columns</p>
            <p>Then again, on small screens I should be the second element.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="large-6 small-12 large-pull-6 columns ">
            <p>B:  On large screens, I should be the second element in the row, i.e. 6 columns</p>
            <p>Of course, on small screens, I should show up first!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Try this..

It should be `large-pull` and `large-push`.

Comment: it works..something wrong with the fiddle.classes with large are not applied in fiddle..check this-http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Koafk.